# How to kill tcp connection with CLOSE_WAIT state

Tags: tcp, tomcat5.5

I found a problem on my web application, hibernate connections does not close properly.
but given the complexity of the web application, it takes at least 15 - 30 days.

In the meantime I wanted to manually close the connection.

In that way I can close this connection without restart tomcat?
There is a command that I can use for kill this pool of connection?

I have found an error in hibernate configuration, to solve

```
#netstat -anp |grep 3306 |grep CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:172.18.11.4:50750    ::ffff:172.18.11.8:3306     CLOSE_WAIT  4203/java           
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:172.18.11.4:36192    ::ffff:172.18.11.8:3306     CLOSE_WAIT  4203/java           
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:172.18.11.4:36215    ::ffff:172.18.11.8:3306     CLOSE_WAIT  4203/java           
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:172.18.11.4:36211    ::ffff:172.18.11.8:3306     CLOSE_WAIT  4203/java           
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:172.18.11.4:57820    ::ffff:172.18.11.8:3306     CLOSE_WAIT  4203/java           
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:172.18.11.4:36213    ::ffff:172.18.11.8:3306     CLOSE_WAIT  4203/java           
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:172.18.11.4:36159    ::ffff:172.18.11.8:3306     CLOSE_WAIT  4203/java
```

etc....

CentOS 6.0 running Tomcat 5.5 and Mysql 5.5.

Comment: "but given the complexity of the web application, it takes at least 15 -30 days" - no this is nothing to do with complexity of the application (code).

Comment: Exactly, this is a *bug,* and you need to *fix* it.

Answer (score 1):

Always call `socket.close()`. See also [how to close JDBC resources properly every time](http://blog.shinetech.com/2007/08/04/how-to-close-jdbc-resources-properly-every-time/).

If you can't fix the server, add the following lines
to `/etc/init.d/inetinit`

```
/usr/sbin/ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_close_wait_interval 1500
/usr/sbin/ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_keepalive_interval 1500
```

and reboot. According to http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Unix/Solaris/Q_20568402.html

Alternatively, on Linux, try [`tcpkill`](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-3-man/tcpkill) (part of [`dsniff`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSniff)) or [`cutter`](http://www.lowth.com/cutter/).

Comment: ndd is utlity for solaris, where is for centos?

Comment: sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_close_wait_interval=1500
error: "net.ipv4.tcp_close_wait_interval" is an unknown key

Answer (score 0):

There was some other question about this I can't find now. But you can try [killcx](http://killcx.sourceforge.net/) and [cutter](http://digitage.co.uk/digitage/software/linux-security/cutter). <del>I can't find a link to</del> cutter but it's found in debian repos. Make sure to pick the tcp connection killer and not the unit testing framework with same name.

update: there seems to be a windows version [wkillcx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wkillcx)
update2: thanks Xiong Chiamiov for cutter link